# Repeat a sum as a column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

```
WO#  Seg# Part# QTY TotSale FlatSale 
1    1    1     5   35      159
1    1    2     2   100     159
1    2    3     3   50      50
```

I need to calculate the FlatSale/SUM(TotSale) for each Seq# & WO# but do not group Seg# into one row.

I need this

```
WO#  Seg# Part# QTY TotSale FlatSale Calc
1    1    1     5   35      159      1.177
1    1    2     2   100     159      1.177
1    2    3     3   50      50       1
```

With my code I am able to only do the division on each individual line like this:

```sql
 select *, FlatSale/TotSale as Calc from table
```

```
WO#  Seg# Part# QTY TotSale FlatSale Calc
1    1    1     5   35      159      4.54
1    1    2     2   100     159      1.59
1    2    3     3   50      50       1
```

I wouldn't mind leaving my Calc column and adding another column if that's the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
[WO#],[Seg#],[Part#],[QTY],[TotSale],[FlatSale] 
((FlatSale*100)/(SUM([TotSale]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Seg#] ORDER BY [Seg#])))/100 AS Calc
FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: think should include `WO#` in the `partition by`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join. Here's something quick (not tested as I don't have access to mssql at the moment):

```
select *, x.CalcPrice as Calc 
from table t
outer apply (
    select t.FlatSale/SUM(ix.TotSale) CalcPrice 
    from table ix where ix.[WO#] = t.[WO#] 
        and ix.[Seg#] = t.[Seg#]) x
```

Something like that.